# NotifyPropertyChanged not changing my control when I Instanciate a new Source

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to WinForms.
I'm trying to make a simple binding to my control:

```
numQuality.DataBindings.Add("Text", Config.Workspace.GenerationSetup, dataMember: "DdimSteps", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

In resume, it's a numeric box that I binded to a configuration property, if I change the DdimSteps, the textbox changes as well.

The problem is when I need to Instantiate a new Config.Workspace, it don't refresh the textbox.

I have tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged and call the PropertyChanged when the Config.Workspace is changed. But even though the method is being called, NumericBox does not updates.

Comment: As I'm understanding, the databind loses its connection to the datasource because I replaced the object with a new one.
Did I really need to rebind all my controls again every time I Instanciate the Config.Workspace?

Comment: Databinding is listening for the value of the `DdimSteps` property to change in your `Config.Workspace.GenerationSetup` object.  If you keep making a new `Config.Workspace.GenerationSetup` instance, then yes, you lost your databinding connection.  If you want this to work, just use the one original instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a BindingSource with DataSource set to Config.Workspace.GenerationSetup then you will bind textbox to that BindingSource instead. then if you want to change objet, set DataSource property of DataBindingSource

Comment: For future help, edit DataBindingSource to BindingSource

Comment: This works so great that I don't even had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yeah most people dosnt know it. it subscribes to changes via PropertyDescriptor for current edited object. So if you programatically change values you wont observe changses. if this is a requirement change via PropertyDescriptor obtained by TypeDescriptor.GetProperties...